# Making a Text View bulleted in Xcode with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, textview, bulletedlist

I am trying to make a text view that is strictly bulleted.  So when you start typing it makes a bullet.  When you hit enter it will make a bullet. I found some code that will make a bulleted list but it only writes some text into the text view initially:

```
myTextView.text = @"\u2022";
```

And this is a text view not a text field (dont think that makes a difference) and it is for ios but does anybody know how you would do this?

Comment: I think that if there was a way to notify the app when the return key was pressed you could then insert a bullet and it would be like a string segment or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This textView delegate is your friend:

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

So what happens is as people enter text, you get this delegate method, and you can see the text that WILL be added if you return YES. Now you cannot change the replacement text, but what you can do is ask the UITextView for all the current text, modify it as you wish, then return NO.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly:) Running into a bit of trouble.  I don't know how you ask the UITextView for all the current text.  I am not very familiar with all the methods yet.

Comment: UITextView *tv; NSString *theText = tv.text; This is all in the class description. You need to browse them to find out more about the classes you are using.